# Renaming files that have specific format like text.*

Tags: python, rename

I have a folder containing 1000 coordination files with this pattern: coord.* (* is timestep that is starting from 0 and increased by 10000 each time (`coord.0` , `coord.10000` , ...). I want to rename all of them to `coordN.*` (keeping the timestamp, only adding letter N). Any suggestion on how I should do that on python?

Comment: First, [find all files that match your pattern](https://www.google.com/search?q=find+all+files+matching+pattern+python). Then, [replace `"coord"` with `"coordN"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=replace+substring+pytho). Then [move the old filename to the new filename](https://www.google.com/search?q=move+file+python).

Comment: The key to being an effective programmer is to break up your task into smaller tasks and then doing those tasks. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `glob` for get all files with pattern `coord.*` in your path and rename them with `os.rename`.

```
import os
import glob

path = 'Files/'

for file in glob.glob(path+'coord.*'):
    f,s = file.split('.',1)
    file_new = f+'N.'+s
    os.rename(file, file_new)
```

First filenames:

```
coord.1.txt
coord.1.png
```

After renaming:

```
coordN.1.txt
coordN.1.png
```